# Сбой подключения к удаленному серверу. Клиенту WinRM не удается обработать запрос

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

> *PS C:\Windows\system32> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName serv1*
>
> Enter-PSSession : Сбой подключения к удаленному серверу `serv1`. Сообщение об ошибке: Клиенту WinRM не удается обработать запрос. Если применяемая схема проверки подлинности отличается от Kerberos или компьютер клиента не входит в домен, необходимо использовать транспорт HTTPS или добавить компьютер назначения к значениям параметра конфигурации *TrustedHosts*. Чтобы настроить *TrustedHosts*, используйте `winrm.cmd`. Обратите внимание, что в списке *TrustedHosts* могут находиться компьютеры, не прошедшие проверку подлинности. Чтобы получить дополнительные сведения об этом, выполните следующую команду: `winrm help config`. Подробности см. в разделе справки «[about_Remote_Troubleshooting](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh847850.aspx)».
>
> строка:1 знак:1
>
> ```
> + Enter-PSSession -ComputerName serv1
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (serv1:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSRemotingTransportException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Очень помогла статья «[Настройка удаленного взаимодействия в PowerShell](http://windowsnotes.ru/powershell-2/nastrojka-udalennogo-vzaimodejstviya-v-powershell-chast-1/)».

Answer (score 0):

В [статье](http://windowsnotes.ru/powershell-2/nastrojka-udalennogo-vzaimodejstviya-v-powershell-chast-1/), на которую сослался Oleg, нашел вот такую команду, помогло

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value SRV1.contoso.com
```

Comment: "В статье выше нашел  ..." - выше или ниже понятия относительные и зависят от настройки сортировки ответов в теме - "текущие/старые/голоса". Скопируйте ссылку и укажите её явно в вашем ответе.